# What´s wrong reading a xml file?

Tags: javascript

This is the simple html file for reading an xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>simple script javascript</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lector.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>"web is running"</h1>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    <h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
    <pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
</body>
```

and the lector.js is as follows:

```
    function leerArchivo(e) {
    var archivo = e.target.files[0];
    if (!archivo) {
      return;
    }
    var lector = new FileReader();
    lector.onload = function(e) {
      var contenido = e.target.result;
      mostrarContenido(contenido);
    };
    lector.readAsText(archivo);
  }
  function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
    elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
  }
  document.getElementById('file-input')
    .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
console.log(contenido);
```

returning this error:

Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

What´s wrong ?

Comment: does this tag with id `file-input` exists in html? `document.getElementById('file-input')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returning `null`:

```
document.getElementById('file-input')
```

Because the code is executing *before* the element exists on the page.  JavaScript is processed in the order it's found in the HTML document, even before the full document is finished loading.

You can move the JavaScript to the end of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>simple script javascript</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>"web is running"</h1>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    <h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
    <pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
    <script src="scripts/lector.js"></script>
</body>
```

(The jQuery library can still load at the beginning of the page if you want because it doesn't immediately try to interact with the page, it just initializes itself.  But since your script tries to interact with the page, it needs to wait until the page loads.)

Alternatively, since you're loading jQuery anyway, you can use it to easily wait until the document is ready.  Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
    console.log(contenido);
});
```